# <Application> has active assertions beyond permitted time - iPhone 5S only, fine on iPhone 5, 4s and 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7, nsurlconnection

I'm getting the following crash report for an app that is doing background communication with an NSURLconnection in the background with a timeout of 7 seconds:

```
Incident Identifier: 3C862AC5-4226-461B-ACC8-6F080D2FDFDB
CrashReporter Key:   119b92a02f2002d19cf9f0b80d48362ac24a5d3e
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,2
Process:             xxx [1971]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/33D1EAC9-8D24-4E40-805B-BD7C4FCD96FD/xxx.app/xxx
Identifier:          com.xx.xxx
Version:             1.0.0 (1.0.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2013-10-30 19:50:38.812 +1000
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.3 (11B511)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  2

Application Specific Information:
xxx[1971] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x17046ad40> identifier: Called by xxx, from unknown method process: xxx[1971] permittedBackgroundDuration: 180.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:1971 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep  preventSuspendOnSleep 
)}

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 0.440 (user 0.440, system 0.000), 4% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.000, 0% CPU
```

This occurs when attempting to use the following pieces of code:

```
+(NSURLRequest*)updateLocation4SampleRequest_withUserId:(NSString*)userId userAPIToken:(NSString*)userAPIToken p1:(CLLocation*)p1 p2:(CLLocation*)p2 p3:(CLLocation*)p3 p4:(CLLocation*)p4 accuracy:(CLLocationAccuracy)accuracy
{
//    return [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat: updateLocation4SampleRequestURL, OTNRequestURL, userId, userAPIToken, p1.coordinate.latitude, p1.coordinate.longitude, p2.coordinate.latitude, p2.coordinate.longitude, p3.coordinate.latitude, p3.coordinate.longitude, p4.coordinate.latitude, p4.coordinate.longitude, accuracy] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]]];

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat: updateLocation4SampleRequestURL, userId, userAPIToken, p1.coordinate.latitude, p1.coordinate.longitude, p2.coordinate.latitude, p2.coordinate.longitude, p3.coordinate.latitude, p3.coordinate.longitude, p4.coordinate.latitude, p4.coordinate.longitude, accuracy];

    NSLog(@"%@",post);
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:OTNRequestURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:7];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    return request;
}
```

And the function that calls it and starts an asyncrequest.

```
// start the Link Maker search
        NSURLRequest* request = [OTNUtil updateLocation4SampleRequest_withUserId:userId     userAPIToken:user_api_token p1:p1 p2:p2 p3:p3 p4:p4     accuracy:OTNDataManager.app.currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy];
        NSLog(@"%@, (UPDATELOCATION) user id: %@",[request URL], userId);


        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:_requestOperationQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* data, NSError* error) {
            //The first checkin has occurred bool is used to skip the splash screen.
            self.firstCheckinHasOccurred = YES;

            // Save the downloaded data
            NSError* jsonError = nil;
            NSDictionary* resultDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];
            if(jsonError != nil) {
                // do something with the error here
                NSLog(@"JSON Error: %@", jsonError);
                //    callback(nil, jsonError);
                if (OTNDataManager.shared.settingsAutoCheckin) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [OTNDataManager.app setLocationUpdateInterval:15.0 * 60.0];
                    });
                }

            } else if (resultDictionary != nil) {
              <SNIP....>
            }
          }];
```

To confirm... I am only seeing this on the iPhone 5S running 7.0.3, but not two separate iPhone 5, one running 7.0.3 and the other 6.1.4. It is also working on an iPhone 4S running 7.0.2. Also, it doesn't happen if running code while tethered to Xcode, only when running a compiled version of the app in release mode.

If anyone has any idea what is going on here, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is annoying which is hard to debug by breakpoint, I suggest you try some trick when app resign active as following, to apply for more time from system:

```
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTaskIdentifier = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{


        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskIdentifier];
        backgroundTaskIdentifier = backgroundTaskIdentifier;
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

These are watchdog timeout crash reports, which you can recognize by the infamous "ate bad food" (0x8badf00d) exception code. More info on how to decipher the crash log and potential solutions can be found at :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1693/_index.html